# Dynamics NAV Odata request returns HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: json, odata, microsoft-dynamics

Am calling dynamics NAV odata API for customercard to create  a new customer using php's curl. Below are the parameters used

```
$url = "http://XXX:7048/DynamicsNAV110/OData/Company('CRONUS%20International%20Ltd.')/CustomerCard?%24format=json";
$body["name"] = $company_name;
$body["Phone_No"]= $phone;
$body["address"] = $company_address;
$json_args = json_encode($body);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, [
'Connection: Keep-Alive',  
'Accept: application/json',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_args);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXX:YYY" );

$verbose = fopen('temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

However I keep getting 415 error "Unsupported Media Type.

```
Accept: */* Content-Length: 50 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse < HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type < Content-Length: 98 < Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8 < Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the issue.
I replaced the httpheader with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
and that fixed the issue.